# What really is Ketiv/Kri

Tags: tanach, mesorah-tradition

Basic question but:
What exactly is Ketiv vs Kri? How do these differentiations pop up? Which one is more authoritative and why is it more prevalent in Nach vs the Torah?

Thanks

Comment: On a related note, I've always wondered if the entire Torah is conceptually divided into two parallel (albeit mostly identical) versions, or if it only forks at particular words. If it's the latter, does the frequent occurrence of הוא read as היא count as a kri/ksiv, or does that fall into another class? What about words that can be spelled חסר or מלא?

Comment: @shmosel Similarly נערה is (almost) always spelled נער in the Torah, for some reason.